# Find a file that doesn't include specific characters

Tags: grep, find, wildcards

I want to find a specific file that *doesn't* start with `a`,`k`,`G` or `Q` and in which the *third* letter in the name is not a *digit*.

I have tried many links, but found nothing regarding to this composite problem.

Comment: `find . -name '[^akGQ]?[^0-9]*'`

Comment: The _third letter_, by definition is a letter, so not a digit. Did you mean the _third character_ instead?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean *third character* as opposed to *third letter*;

```
find . -name '[!akGQ]?[!0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

In ksh you will have the negation file globbing pattern `!( ... )`. So you could write

```
!([akGQ]?[0-9]*)
```

Comment: That would match on `abc` or `123`.